# how to change static image exist in css to be dynamic recover in controller uses laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, image

i want to make a blade profile, i find a template profile, i fetch the give from user auth with these images, i want to display these images, but in template the images are static in css. here is the code to explain more.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
         return view('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="cover-photo"></div>
```

**css**

```
.cover-photo {
  width: 980px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/980/250);
}
```

I tried

```
<div class="cover-photo">{{ Voyager::image($users->image) }}</div>
```

but it displays image link instead of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this instead

```
<div class="cover-photo" style="background-image: url({{ Voyager::image($users->image) }})"></div>
```